# Django object level permission using default auto-created model permissions

Tags: django

By default, Django adds 4 permissions for each registered model:

- add_modelname
- change_modelname
- delete_modelname
- view_modelname

When a user has one of these permissions it applies to all instances of that model. That's not what I want, I want per instance permission.

When the creator (`created_by` in database, or some related table of users with access) has `delete_modelname` permission he can delete only that instance, and not some other created by another user.

I've been looking at other answers and none of them mention the auto-created CRUD permissions that are created for all models, it's mostly new tables or third-party libraries.

What about giving creators of models these permissions (add, change, delete, view) which normally would give them access to all other models, but also having a custom auth backend which checks the object:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class ObjectPermissionBackend(BaseBackend):
    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return False
        return obj.created_by == user_obj.pk # or something like this
```

And then using it:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 'path.to.ObjectPermissionBackend']
```

Is there some downside to this?